# Finding the end of a Drag and Drop operation in QAbstractItemView

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt4, qt5

I created custom proxy model inherited by QSortFilterProxyModel. My source model for the above mentioned proxy model is also a custom model inherited by QAbstractTableModel. Then I set my custom proxy model to a QTableView.

In this custom proxy model, I reimplemented the mimeData(..) function. It is as follows.

```
QMimeData* CustomProxyModel::mimeData( const QModelIndexList & rListIndexes ) const
{
    QMimeData *pMimeData = new QMimeData();

    //some code here

    connect(pMimeData, SIGNAL( destroyed(QObject*) ), this, SLOT( OnDestroyDraggedItem() ) );

    return pMimeData;
}
```

In Qt4.7, soon after the user dropped an item of the QTableView into somewhere, OnDestroyDraggedItem() slot was called. In other words, QMimeData object is deleted soon after the drag and drop operation.

But in Qt 5.1, OnDestroyDraggedItem() slot is never called. In other words, QMimeData object is never deleted after a drag and drop operation.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Or Has Qt 5.1 a memory leak after a drag and drop operation ?
Is there another way to find a end of a drag and drop operation ?

Comment: Are you sure you have nothing better to connect to than the destroyed signal?

Comment: That is the only solution, I know to find the end of a drag and drop operation. If you have other idea, please share it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late - but can't you just inherit `QMimeData` and do something in the destructor?
Should be small and safe code of course - throwing exceptions in destructors can cause strange behavior :)

Comment: And - just in case you're reading this :) - please note there seems to be a problem with current Qt: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37846843/1668622