# Memory leak in Qt5? How to get QMimeData deleted?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, ownership

I just provided an answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23709529/1668622) question and wanted to provide a working example when I noticed that newly created `QMimeData` instance returned by `QListModel::mimeData()` won't get deleted until the application gets terminated.

So this is not a *real* memory leak since Qt handles all `QMimeData` instances on shutdown but you only have to drag&drop long enough and put the right content into your mime data to let the memory run full.

Did I miss something? Is there a way to tell Qt to delete the `QMimeData` instances as soon as they are not needed any more?

**Please note:**

I know that every instance of `QMimeData` gets deleted by Qt automatically on program termination.
My problem here is not a real memory leak as reported by `valgrind` or `cppcheck` but it looks like the multiple and potentially very large `QMimeData` instances get not cleaned up at runtime which blows up memory consumption as well.

**Example Code:**

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <iostream>

struct TrackedMimeData : public QMimeData {
   TrackedMimeData(const QString & text) {
      std::cout << this << std::endl;
      setText(text);
   }
   ~TrackedMimeData() {
       std::cout << "~" << this << std::endl;
   }
};

struct MyListWidget : QListWidget {
   MyListWidget() {
      setDragEnabled(true);
      addItem("item1");
      addItem("item2");
   }
   QMimeData * mimeData(const QList<QListWidgetItem *>) const override {
      return new TrackedMimeData("hello");
   }
};

int main(int argsc, char *argsv[]) {
   QApplication application(argsc, argsv);
   MyListWidget gui;
   gui.show();
   return application.exec();
}
```

Example output looks like this:

```
0xa58750
0xa4e0f0
~0xa4e0f0
0xa3c6c0
~0xa3c6c0
0xa51880
0xa5ecd0
0xa31f50
0xa57db0
0xa5afc0
~0xa5afc0
0xa5aa70
~0xa5aa70
------ CLOSE WINDOW
~0xa58750
~0xa51880
~0xa5ecd0
~0xa31f50
~0xa57db0
```

The destructors get called *before* closing the application only when the drop get's accepted.

Btw. I'm on a home-grown Qt **5.6 @1fcdb6cafcf** - on one computer and on **5.6.0-19.fc23** Fedora 23 precompiled on another. So I doubt it's just a temporary development state.

Comment: `QMimeData` inherits `QObject` and stores its data internally as a `QVector` of strings and `QVariant` pairs. It has the same memory management limitations any other `QObject`-derived class experiences.

Comment: `cppcheck` would not find anything in this example because the `QMimeData` instance gets deleted at the end. But until then I might have stored gigabytes of data in thousands of instances of new `QMimeData` instances - which is - I admit - not a classical memory leak.

Comment: Are you actually seeing excessive memory consumption, or just concerned that it may happen?

Comment: And this is, ladies and gentlemen, how you reap the well-deserved sweet, sweet karma for having a clear question with a self-contained test case. Should be a case study for everyone whose questions are downvoted and/or closed. I figure if it's worth commenting the downsides, it's worth commenting the upsides, too, to reinforce good behavior. Well done.

Comment: @Jon: I'm pretty sure there is memory loss but in the first place I wanted to track the lifetime of a `QMimeData` or `QDrag` instance to know when a drag&drop operation gets aborted. Currently there's no way for me to know e.g. when to hide some "on demand drop widget".

Comment: There's only a leak if you don't pass the `QMimeData` on to an appropriate handler. It looks like a case of *potential* leaks if the newly created `QMimeData` object is not given a parent by the object creating it (or if you don't delete it directly).

Answer (score 2):

There is a memory leak only if you forget to delete the pointer returned by `mimeData()`. You have to manage the ownership as with any pointer.

For instance, if you pass the `mimeData()` returned pointer to a `QDrag` object using `setMimeData()`, he will take ownership of it, and will take care of deleting it at the end of the drag operation. There is no memory leak in this case.

See : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#setMimeData

Comment: I use a `QListWidget` which derives from `QAbstractItemView` and creates/handles the `QDrag` object. I only create the `QMimeData` which then gets owned by the `QDrag` object which I don't have access to.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation says that QDrag::setMimeData passes ownership to the QDrag object. This means the QMimeData object will be deleted when QDrag is deleted

Comment: Ok, but then the `QDrag` object does not get deleted in time - I'll correct this detail in my question but the issue is the same.

Comment: As I said in my comment - I don't create `QDrag` manually - `QListWidget` does that for me. I'll add a working example as soon as possible!

Comment: If you let the widget handle the QDrag, it is stated in the documentation that it will be destroyed on time. Do you really observe an actual memory leak related to QDrag ?

Comment: I've added an example which reproduces the described behavior. I'm not sure whether this is a memory leak but neither I know why it shouldn't..

Comment: `QDrag` objects are internally managed by a private singleton class, `QDragManager`. Thus, no leak.

Comment: That's not a very useful definition of a leak. I can start/abort as many drag operations as I want and the underlying `QDrag` and `QMimeData` instances will **never** be cleaned up in program lifetime despite they're not used any more. For me this is a leak.

Answer (score 1):

It should be happening, if it isn't, then it's a bug - there's nothing you can do about it, other than reporting it if it hasn't been reported yet.

I can't reproduce it on OS X with Qt 5.6. It may be platform-specific, or an already fixed bug in an old Qt version. As soon as I release the mouse button at the end of the drag, the mime data gets deleted. The call stack when the destructor executes has the `QDrag` destructor called from the event loop via `deleteLater` somewhere. I've used your code verbatim.

Sidebar: It could be made just a bit more minimal, if you really wanted it as short as possible. Here's what I got, although I agree it's mostly splitting hair. Your question beats 99% other questions by **providing a working example - big kudos for that**! The things that I think matter for brevity are:

1. Inclusion of the entire needed Qt module(s).
2. Use of `qDebug` instead of `std::cout` & al, it saves an include and is more Qt style.
3. Access specifiers don't matter if you use `struct` anyway.
4. Generally speaking, destructors are either virtual in the public base class, or they can never be without succumbing to slicing. So you don't have to spell that out.

I have example code where I don't follow this, of course. I like to call it legacy code :)

```
#include <QtWidgets>

struct TrackedMimeData : QMimeData {
   TrackedMimeData(const QString & text) {
      qDebug() << this;
      setText(text);
   }
   ~TrackedMimeData() {
      qDebug() << "~" << this;
   }
};

struct MyListWidget : QListWidget {
   MyListWidget() {
      setDragEnabled(true);
      addItem("item1");
      addItem("item2");
   }
   QMimeData * mimeData(const QList<QListWidgetItem *>) const override {
      return new TrackedMimeData("hello");
   }
};

int main(int argsc, char *argsv[]) {
   QApplication application(argsc, argsv);
   MyListWidget gui;
   gui.show();
   return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't see any output from qDebug - neither on terminal nor in QtCreator. But the output with `cout` proves the destructor doesn't get called (in my case)

Comment: @frans Weird... What platform & Qt version is that on? It's definitely a bug. Please report if not reported already.